# Next.js: Add 'style' to element in event-listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

As in the title descriped, i tray to add style to an dom-element in nexts.js Typescript and i get "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element' " message in Visual Studio Code. I cant figure out what is the problem and via google search i cant get to the answwer. Maybe because i dont understand the problem, so its really hard to say if i  ask the right question...

Some can give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Comment: Is this from [Fireship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGe3pS5LqEw)?

Comment: @caTS oh ok, thans for the comment. I change it and know it for the future. And yes, a great part of the code is from fireship, i've implement a modified version on my portfolio page. I post it than if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the elements, and you already check if they exist, so there is no need to call `document.querySelector` again:

```
anchor.style.filter = `hue-rotate(${angleDeg}deg)`;
pupil.style.transform = `rotate(${90 + angleDeg}deg)`;
```

And also, you should mark the result from `querySelector` to `HTMLElement` by giving it the generic parameter since it'll complain that `style` doesn't exist on type `Element`:

```
const anchor = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("#anchor");
const pupil = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("#pupil");
```

If needed, you can change `HTMLElement` to a more specific type. For example, if `anchor` is an `a` tag, you can change it to `HTMLAnchorElement`.

Also, make sure to subscribe to Fireship if you have't already :x

Comment: Oh, thanks for that answer! OFC i know that i dont have to querySelector again, but i thought it make the problem more visible, that i cant style a dom-element neither if i querySelector it in the same declaration. I'm impressed about the solution, it's the first time ever that i have to mark a dom-element with the <HTMLElement> tag, i didnt even know that this exists. Thanks you so much! I can go study the reasons now :-)